# Extract a substring from a string in Ruby using a regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex, string, substring

How can I extract a substring from within a string in Ruby?

Example:

```
String1 = "<name> <substring>"
```

I want to extract `substring` from `String1` (i.e. everything within the last occurrence of `<` and `>`).

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
String1.scan(/<([^>]*)>/).last.first
```

`scan` creates an array which, for each `<item>` in `String1` contains the text between the `<` and the `>` in a one-element array (because when used with a regex containing capturing groups, scan creates an array containing the captures for each match). `last` gives you the last of those arrays and `first` then gives you the string in it.

Answer (score 363):

```
"<name> <substring>"[/.*<([^>]*)/,1]
=> "substring"
```

No need to use `scan`, if we need only one result.
No need to use Python's `match`, when we have Ruby's `String[regexp,#]`.

See: http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

Note: `str[regexp, capture] → new_str or nil`

Comment: No need to discredit other perfectly valid (and might I opine, more readable) solutions.

Comment: @coreyward, if they are better, please, argument it. For example, sepp2k's solution is more flexible, and that's why I pointed `if we need only one result` in my solution. And `match()[]` is slower, because it's two methods instead of one.

Comment: This is the fastest of all the methods presented, but even the slowest method takes only 4.5 microseconds on my machine.  I do not care to speculate why this method is faster.  In performance, speculation is _useless_.  Only measurement counts.

Comment: I find this solution more straightforward and to the point (since I am new to Ruby). Thanks.

Comment: @Nakilon Readability can outweigh tiny performance differences when considering the overall success of a product and team, so coreyward made a valid comment. That said, I think `string[regex]` can be just as readable in this scenario, so that's what I used personally.

Comment: Do you mind adding since what ruby version this method is valid? I want to use this solution but now I need to go lookup what version or buy introduced string[regex] (for all I know it's always been there).

Edit: I can only find ruby api docs > 2.0.0 where this method is still valid so it's probably fine to use it: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: @Asaf, if you ask me, then take a look at answer timestamp -- this code was valid in November 2010.

Comment: @Nakilon It's not something I noticed before, but of course it must be valid for at least that long. Thanks for the answer to this question which helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 26):

You can use a regular expression for that pretty easily…

Allowing spaces around the word (but not keeping them):

```
str.match(/< ?([^>]+) ?>\Z/)[1]
```

Or without the spaces allowed:

```
str.match(/<([^>]+)>\Z/)[1]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the last `<>` actually needs to be the last thing in the string. If e.g. the string `foo <bar> baz` is allowed (and supposed to give the result `bar`), this will not work.

Comment: I just went based on the sample string he provided.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a slightly more flexible approach using the `match` method.  With this, you can extract more than one string:

```
s = "<ants> <pants>"
matchdata = s.match(/<([^>]*)> <([^>]*)>/)

# Use 'captures' to get an array of the captures
matchdata.captures   # ["ants","pants"]

# Or use raw indices
matchdata[0]   # whole regex match: "<ants> <pants>"
matchdata[1]   # first capture: "ants"
matchdata[2]   # second capture: "pants"
```

Answer (score 7):

A simpler scan would be:

```
String1.scan(/<(\S+)>/).last
```