# How do I extract strings from a string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, substring

I have a long string, consisting of multiple sentences, of various length, divided by a "`-`".

I want to iterate over the string and extract everything between the `-`'s, preferably to an array.

From another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115115/extract-substring-from-string-ruby) I found something that gets me pretty close, but not all the way:

```
longString.scan( /-([^-]*)-/)
```

Needless to say, I am new to Ruby, and especially to RegEx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with using [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split)?

```
longString.split('-')
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use [`string.split()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split)?

```
longString.split('-');
```