# Extract text from a string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I saw a few [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115115/extract-substring-from-string-ruby) and came up with the following code. My desired result is **100.02**. The required result is always between **'my launch duration='** and **'mins'**

```
mystring ='2012-07-11 22:30:33,536  INFO: 00/00/164/ABCTimeTest: my launch duration= 100.02 mins|z-vndn'
mypattern = /^.*=([^mins]*)/
subst = mystring.match(mypattern)
puts subst
```

**output with the above code:** 2012-07-11 22:30:33,536  INFO: 00/00/164/ABCTimeTest: my launch duration= 100.02

Whats wrong in my pattern? correct me with my understanding of this pattern.

```
#/
#^.*=             ## move from start till = (now I have reached till '=')
#([^mins])        ## capture somethings that starts with mins (thats my 100.2)
#/
```

Comment: `([^mins]*)` doesn't do what you expect. That means "capture zero or more of anything that isn't "m", "i", "n" or "s".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me.  Don't `puts subst`, as `subst` contains the `MatchData` object. The capture is inside `$1` or `subst[1]`.

```
mystring ='2012-07-11 22:30:33,536  INFO: 00/00/164/ABCTimeTest: my launch duration= 100.02 mins|z-vndn'
mypattern = /^.*=([^mins]*)/
subst = mystring.match(mypattern)

# Contains extra whitespace, so call .strip
puts $1.strip
# 100.02

# Or ...
puts subst[1].strip
# 100.02
```

To get the `100.02` without the extra whitespace, you can use the following:

```
mypattern = /^.*=\s*([^\smins]*)/
```

Comment: `$1` is super old-school Perl and might confuse maintainers unfamiliar with what it is. `subst` contains all the information you need. `$1` is also global and can get stomped if you're not careful to use it right away.

Comment: $1 is not super old-school Perl. It is standard regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is correct but you're not using the results correctly. `subst` is a match object, not the contents of the capture. What you want instead is:

```
# Show first captured result
puts subst[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`[^mins]` does not match any sequence of characters that's not the exact string `mins`.  It actually means one single character that isn't an 'm', 'i', 'n' or an 's'.

To match the desired text, try something like:

`/my launch duration= ([0-9.]*) mins/`

This means match a sequence of 0-9 and a period any number of times, but it must be between `my launch duration=` and `mins`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something simple like:

```
mystring ='2012-07-11 22:30:33,536  INFO: 00/00/164/ABCTimeTest: my launch duration= 100.02 mins|z-vndn'
mystring[/(\S+) mins/, 1] # => "100.02"
```