# Fetching the substring contained between two specific words

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, substring

I wanted to know how to proceed when I am interested in the text contained between particular words using ruby.
eg.

```
@var = "Hi, I want to extract container_start ONLY THIS DYNAMIC CONTENT container_end from the message contained between the container_start and container_end "
```

Now I want to extract the CAPITALIZED content from the string i.e. dynamic but always contained within the two containers (`container_start` and `container_end`)

Comment: which technology you are using?

Comment: Thanks, working on ruby on rails

Comment: if you look into html tag matcher regex, you will probably know how to grab it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115115/extract-substring-from-string-ruby (modify it to suit your needs)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple regular expression would do:

```
@var = "Hi, I want to extract container_start **ONLY THIS DYNAMIC CONTENT** container_end from the message contained between the container_start and container_end "
@var[/container_start(.*?)container_end/, 1] # => " **ONLY THIS DYNAMIC CONTENT** "
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was a BANG ON.

Comment: If I hadn't found this post (or a similar post), how would I have found this answer? This strikes me as a solution which isn't very intuitive. Just curious.

Comment: @victor-deryagin ..  I am new to these, so a very basic question ,why is that 1 used in regexp,

Answer (score 4):

Using the same regex given by Victor, you can also do

```
var.split(/container_start(.*?)container_end/)[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a non-regex answer, you can also use two .splits with selection of array entries.

```
=> @var = "Hi, I want to extract container_start ONLY THIS DYNAMIC CONTENT container_end from the message contained between the container_start and container_end "
=> @var.split("container_start ")[1].split(" container_end")[0]
=> "ONLY THIS DYNAMIC CONTENT"
```

.split splits the string at the text in the quotes. The [1] selects the portion AFTER that text. For the second cut, you want the portion BEFORE the "container_end" so you select [0].

You need to leave the spaces in the two .split substrings to remove leading and trailing spaces.  Alternately, use .lstrip and .rstrip.

If there were more "container_start" and "container_end" strings you would need to adjust the array selectors to pick the correct portion of @var between those two substrings.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add something important that I got from [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html)

```
@var = "Hi, I want to extract container_start \n\nONLY \nTHIS\n DYNAMIC\n CONTENT\n\n container_end from the message contained between the container_start and container_end "
@var[/container_start(.*?)container_end/m, 1]
```

Took the except:

```
/./ - Any character except a newline.
/./m - Any character (the m modifier enables multiline mode)
```