# Regex Non greedy match between two characters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this following string:

```
message_id = "7bb19406-f97a-47b3-b42c-40868d2cef5b-1661496224@example.com"
```

I would like to extract the last part between `- .* @` which is `1661496224`

With forward and backward lookup, it starts from first matches of `-` but I want to match from last match of `-`:

```rb
#!/bin/ruby

message_id = "7bb19406-f97a-47b3-b42c-40868d2cef5b-1661496224@example.com"
message_id.match(/(?<=\-).*(?=\@)
```

**output:**

```
#<MatchData "f97a-47b3-b42c-40868d2cef5b-1661496224">
```

How to capture the least match (`1661496224`) between two characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the message_id does not contain spaces, you might use:

```
(?<=-)[^-@\s]+(?=@)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K96MqJ/1)

If there can not be any more @ chars or hyphens after the @ till the end of the string, you can add that to the assertion.

```
(?<=-)[^-@\s]+(?=@[^\s@-]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qsxTDD/1)

Another option with a capture group:

```
-([^-@\s]+)@[^-@\s]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sVe0YF/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can match all the non-dash characters that are followed by a `@`:

```
[^-]+(?=@)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/bnDxd2

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4115115/9758194) post on SO; what about:

```
s = "7bb19406-f97a-47b3-b42c-40868d2cef5b-1661496224@example.com"

puts s[/-([^-@]*)@/,1] #assuming a single '@', otherwise:
puts s.scan(/-([^-@]*)@/).last.first
```

Both print:

```
1661496224
```

[image]