# Non-greedy lookbehind - selecting text between two characters with criteria

Tags: regex, positive-lookbehind

There are plenty (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73497268/regex-non-greedy-match-between-two-characters) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232220/how-to-non-greedy-multiple-lookbehind-matches)) of answers regarding a non-greedy lookbehind and a regex that selects text between two characters. But the solutions I found so far don't rely on having criteria to the text it needs to select.

Given the example below the non-greedy lookbehind effect is nullified as soon as a criteria to the text it needs to select comes into play, e.g. when `(?<=>)[^<>]+(?=<)` becomes `(?<=>).+rary.+ring.+(?=<)`

https://regex101.com/r/A4Ks1k/3

So the question is, how do I select the text, with some 'fuzzy' criteria like `.*rary.*ring.*`, between to specific characters, that can occur more then once and that span multiple lines?

Edit: to answer in the comments; yes, don't match `<` and `>` in between the two characters within which a match needs to be made.

Comment: You are using a lookbehind assertion that asserts a `>` directly to the left without a quantifier so the lookbehind by itself is not non-greedy. Do you mean do don't want to match `<` and `>` in between? `(?<=>)[^<>]*rary[^<>]*ring[^<>]*(?=<)` https://regex101.com/r/CuhjtD/1

Comment: Or use a capture group to avoid your lookarounds? Like so: [`(>\s*([^<>]*rary[^<>]*ring[^<>]*?)\s*<)`](https://regex101.com/r/E7soPv/1)

Comment: Both comments answer my question. @The fourth brid if you post your comment as an answer I can mark it as being the correct answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to match `<` and `>` then you can use the negated character  class `[^<>]` as you already suggested in you question.

Make the quantifier optional with the asterix `*` because `.+` matches 1 or more times any character.

Use that character class at the places where you now use `.+`

In your regex101 example you have the s flag to have the dot match a newline. When you use `[^<>]*` you can omit that flag as the negated character class also matches a newline.

```
(?<=>)[^<>]*rary[^<>]*ring[^<>]*(?=<)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CuhjtD/1)